# Create Procedure that have parametre?

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

this is my code :

```
using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection cn = new   
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(
            Properties.Settings.Default.CONNNConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cm = new 
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
            cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cm.Connection = cn;
            cm.CommandText="CREATE  PROCEDURE `GetMovement`(RefArtt vARCHAR(20),idos INTEGER) "+
"BEGIN "+
"SET @Qt=0; "SELECT * ,@Qt:=@Qt+qteliv-qtesor as stock FROM tableInOut;"+
"End";
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();}
```

Exception : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''@Qt'=0; SELECT * ...

Comment: you haven't declared the @Qt parametre

Comment: Code snippet is for CSS / HTML / JS. It is not suitable for C# code.

Comment: the query works fine if i execute it from from sql IDE, but i deos not with c# code!!

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your query 100%:

```
SELECT * ,@Qt:=@Qt+qteliv-qtesor as stock FROM tableInOut;
```

If you can explain so that I adjust my code if needed, but here is an example:

```
using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection cn = new   
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(
            Properties.Settings.Default.CONNNConnectionString))
{
    cn.Open();
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cm = new 
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
    cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cm.Connection = cn;
    cm.CommandText=@"
    DELIMITER //
     CREATE PROCEDURE GetMovement(IN RefArtt VARCHAR(20), IN idos INTEGER)
       BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM tableInOut 
        WHERE ref = RefArtt AND id = idos;
       END //
    DELIMITER ; 
    ";
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```